# adding sliders in R leaflet app

Tags: r, leaflet, sliders

Is it possible to add a slider in R that can change certain values which are visualized?

For a project I want to make a suitability map with a certain amount of layers. The user of the map should be able to change the weights that the different layers contribute to the suitability. 
After some research I found that this is possible in javascript, however I never used javascript.

Comment: Sounds to me like a job for shiny

Comment: Shiny is exactly what I was looking for! If you put your question below I'll mark it as correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be achievable with **shiny**.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too open-ended.

> however I never used javascript

Start by reading https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/leafletR/leafletR.pdf and then https://github.com/chgrl/leafletR .